# How to map custom directive to my html page in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am very new in angularJs please guide me ,i have created custom directive called testDirective in separate file and my controller and config files are in separate files i want to use my custom directive in my html page but while loading the application that custom element is loading but not able to fetch content of directive i guess m missing some sort of mapping .kindly help me

```
//this is testDirective.js 


var app=angular.module('mytodoApp');
app.directive('testDirective',function(){

return {
    restrict:'E',
    template:'<h2>This is comes from directive</h2>'

};

});

 var app=angular.module('mytodoApp');
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });

  < test-directive>
  < /test-directive>
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet/jsFiddle/Plunkr. Your code is not readable as of now.

Comment: Make sure the <script> for the directive file is in the html page. Look for errors in the console.

Comment: @JBNizet is it necessary to inclue all directive file in <script> tag ? if i add inside script tag then its working fine but suppose i have lots of custom directive then at that case it will look weird is there any other way to map

Comment: Err, yes, every JS file that the browser needs to download must be in a script file. Otherwise, how could the browser find the code? During development, having dozens of scripts is not a problem. For production, your build procedure will concatenate and minify all these files, and replace all the <script>s by a single one.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanku so much for your valuable answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bootstrap the Angular app, otherwise the HTML page does not know that you are using AngularJS and what you app has.

Bootstrapping is done by using `ng-app="moduleName"`.

```
<div ng-app="mytodoApp">
  <test-directive></test-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: How to bootstrap my app can  you please elaborate little bit i m new to Angular JS so dont know much about it .

Comment: By using the `ng-app` directive you are saying to AngularJS that in this element all Angular stuff should work. It is the first thing you do when making Angular apps. It is explained on the [Angular home page}(https://angularjs.org/) and in the Tutorial(s) and Developer guide. Please do some research and improve your question to specify what problem to solved, so that people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @JBNizet, you should add your custom directive code, by adding it trough the script tag in your HTML code.

Since browsers can only load 5 to 10 scripts at the same time, it is nessesary in production to concatenate your files with Grunt or Gulp.